# How to see if a GMSPath contains a coordinate

Tags: google-maps-sdk-ios

Google Maps [1.2.0](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/releases) `GMSCoordinateBounds` now contains a [containsCoordinate](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/reference/interface_g_m_s_coordinate_bounds#a88501beb137edd044e4dde9d1f73a0a5) method that I was intending to use for filtering markers that are not on the visibleRegion. Unfortunately, when you init a `GMSCoordinateBounds`, you get bounds that encompass your region or path.

So my question is : is it possible to see if a `CLLocationCoordinate2D` is within a `GMSPath`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I'm answering my own question.  I just needed to use the pointForCoordinate method to see if the point was on the screen.  Works perfectly.

```
for (int i = 0; i < self.visibleLocations.count; i++) {
        Location *location = [self.visibleLocations objectAtIndex:i];
        CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake([location.lat floatValue], [location.lng floatValue]);
        CGPoint markerPoint = [self.googleMap.projection pointForCoordinate:coordinate];
        if (markerPoint.x >= 0 && markerPoint.y >= 0 && markerPoint.x <= self.googleMap.frame.size.width && markerPoint.y <= self.googleMap.frame.size.height) {
            GMSMarker *marker = [GMSMarker markerWithPosition:coordinate];
            marker.title = location.title;
            marker.icon = [UIImage imageNamed:@"search_measle_small.png"];
            marker.map = self.googleMap;
        }
    }
```